# FreeRTOS y CMSIS_OS recibiendo datos desde una interrupcion

Tags: real-time, arm, os, stm32

Estoy utilizando CMSIS_OS V1 con FreeRTOS en un chip STM32F4. Quiero saber si hay alguna forma analoga a FreeRTIS (xQueueReceiveFromISR) de recibir una Queue desde una interrupcion utilizano CMSIS.
Ya que osMessageGet segun entiendo no esta preparado para recibir una Queue desde una interrupcion.